# How to unescape unicode escape sequences in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am loading a html page(UTF-8) content using UrlLoader. All characters in the result are represented as //x?? (where ?? is one symbol).

How can I get normal string from this? (with actual symbols instead of codes).

Comment: Whats is your character encoding?

Comment: Html page character encoding is UTF-8

Comment: What method are you encoding the "html" with?

Comment: please post some code on how to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in languages such as lua.  An escape character can be followed by the same escape character to do the character so:

\ -> \

and

\n -> /n

I don't really know actionscript but I bet you could replace the escape character with two.

Basically replace \ (assuming \ is the escape character (it normally is in most languages)) with \.